# Why is the using alias directive not resolving the conflict between imported class and class in parent namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am working with a code base which includes the following class

```
namespace Api.Data.Models;

// legacy db class entry
public class Log
{
}
```

and in another class I am constructing a model binder which includes some logging

```
using Log = Serilog.Log;

namespace Api.Data.Models.Binding;

public class ModelBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Log.Information("Trying to call Log.Information"); 
        // This cannot resolve symbol Information as it is still pointing at Api.Data.Models.Log
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am trying to do the impossible or if I'm missing something, but **why is the aliasing not resolving my name conflict issue in this scenario**?

There are other ways to solve my specific problem in the code base but I couldn't find a post or question about this particular case online and hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the namespace nomenclature here.

Your `Log` class is declared in `namespace Api.Data.Models` namespace. and `ModelBinder` is declared in the namespace `Api.Data.Models.Binding;`.

`Api.Data.Models` prefix is the same for both the namespaces and that is why it considers your `Log` class when calling  `Log.Information("Trying to call Log.Information");`.

So you could have a different namespace and your issue will be resolved. like for your `Log` class use `namespace Api.Data.Models.Logs`.

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comment, If you can not change the Log file then you could change the namespace of `ModelBinder` class or use a different alias for `Serilog.Log`. Thank you @Fildorfor pointing it out.

Based on OP's comment the local namespace class always takes precedence over the imported class of the same name regardless of aliasing.

Comment: `// legacy db class entry` makes me think OP probably cannot simply change the `Log`-Class's Namespace. But OP could use a (slightly) different alias for `Serilog.Log`, maybe?

Comment: @Fildor thank you for pointing this out, I have updated my answer, please review

Comment: I already +1ed, but looks good for me now. :D

Comment: So local namespace class always takes precedence over imported class of the same name regardless of aliasing? I.e. you cannot "hide" the local namespace class by aliasing in one file?

Comment: @KGEM yes, you got it right

Comment: Thanks @viveknuna! If you could add that detail as well in the answer I think it would make it perfect for anyone stuck in this situation.